# how to solve this concurrency problem?

Tags: java, android

I created a Handler (on Thread1) and I post to it a Runnable from another thread (Thread2). In Thread2 I want to be sure that the posted Runnable was executed in Thread1 before Thread2 continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch. Thread1 creates the latch, submits the Runnable (which needs a reference to the latch), waits on the latch. Runnable counts down the latch.